# How do I populate a drop-down list from XML where text = value1 using Visual Basic?

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down list that needs specific values loaded based on the selection of another drop-down list. I tried doing it from sql with `DISTINCT`set but that doesn't return a proper value:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RMRP_Label, RMRP_Type FROM Table 
WHERE RMRP_Type IN (" + search + ")
```

It keeps changing the DropDownList.SelectedItem.Text value for some reason...
so I made an XML document:

```
<p>

 <param Name = "Intake_ID"
 Value = "!hssCombo"></param>  

 <param Name = "Office_ID"
 Value = "#hssCombo"></param>  

 <param Name = "sub_obj"
 Value = "%hssCombo"></param>  

 <param Name = "Svc_ID"
 Value = "!hssCombo"></param>
```

What I need, for instance, is to populate the dropdown with the `Name` value, from this xml where `Value = "#hssCombo"` or rather where `Value = search` as in the select statement

Answer (score 0):

You can select the value using the following XPath:

> //p/param[@Value='#hssCombo']/@Name

XPath is a standard way to query an XML document, so it's worth learning.  Most any XML tool supports XPath, including the .NET and XSLT.  Here's the meaning of the parts of the path:

- `//p` - `p` is the name of the element that we are looking for.  The double slash indicates that the element can occur anywhere in the document.  If we only wanted to include `p` elements that occur at the root, we could use a single slash to make it an absolute path.
- `/param` - Specifies a sub-element under the `p` element
- `[@Value='#hssCombo']` - Specifies a condition.  Only `//p/param` elements which match the condition will be included.  In this case, the condition specifies that the `Value` attribute of the `param` element must equal `#hssCombo`.  The `@` symbol indicates that `Value` is an attribute, as opposed to a sub-element name.
- `/@Name` - Specifies that we are interested in the value of the `Name` attribute of the the `param` element.

If you are using the `XmlDocument` class, you can select nodes with XPath using the `SelectSingleNode` and `SelectNodes` methods.  For instance:

```
Dim node As XmlNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//p/param[@Value='#hssCombo']/@Name")
If node IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim name As String = node.InnerText
End If
```

Obviously, just as in your SQL example, you can dynamically build the XPath, since it's just a string, like this:

```
doc.SelectSingleNode("//p/param[@Value='" & search & "']/@Name")
```

If you are using the `XDocument` class, you can also select with XPath using the `XPathEvaluate`, `XPathSelectElement`, and `XPathSelectElements` methods.